# looking for guidance with sched in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I'm having trouble with sched in python... Below is my code and it runs but its not doing what I want it to do... Currently if the time is past daily_time = datetime.time(7, 30) then it automatically runs. I dont want it to run if its past 7:30, I want it to "re-register" task for same time tomorrow. How can I correct this?

```
import sys
import sched
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
import datetime

def now_str():
    """Return hh:mm:ss string representation of the current time."""
    t = dt.now().time()
    return t.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


def main():
    def do_something_again(message):
        print 'RUNNING:', now_str(), message
        # Do whatever you need to do here
        # then re-register task for same time tomorrow
        t = dt.combine(dt.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1), daily_time)
        scheduler.enterabs(time.mktime(t.timetuple()), 1,     do_something_again, ('Running again',))

    # Build a scheduler object that will look at absolute times
    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    print 'START:', now_str()
    # Put task for today at 7am on queue. Executes immediately if past 7am
    daily_time = datetime.time(7, 30)
    first_time = dt.combine(dt.now(), daily_time)
    # time, priority, callable, *args
    scheduler.enterabs(time.mktime(first_time.timetuple()), 1,
                   do_something_again, ('Run the first time',))
    scheduler.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: create an if statement with daily_time . If daily time > 7,30 run the re register , else run the code